# Read named table with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

In Excel I have a tabled named "Table1" with unknown number of columns and rows.

How can I get the cells of this table with PHPExcel?

I tried the following, but it's not working.

```
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getNamedRange('Table1');
```

**Edit:**
I see that it gives me the following error, so the method doesn't exists:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::getNamedRange() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gift/view.php on line 20
```

I'm trying now with the following but the problem is that it doesn't recognize the named table. Like it doesn't exists. If I try with a named cell, it works.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->namedRangeToArray('Table1');
```

and error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message 'Named Range Table1 does not exist.' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gift/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php:2511 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gift/view.php(20): PHPExcel_Worksheet->namedRangeToArray('Gifts') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gift/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php on line 2511
```

Comment: What is not working? What is it doing? Errors?

Comment: The `NamedRange` are actually tracked in the `PHPExcel` instance not the `PHPExcel_Worksheet` so you would need to do: `$objPHPExcel->getNamedRange('Table1');` Oddly though, the `namedRangeToArray` **is** a method of `PHPExcel_Worksheet` so that call seems correct. Also `PHPExcel_Worksheet::namedRangeToArray()` does the work of getting that actual named range instance from the `PHPExcel` instance the worksheet is bound to so what you are doing should work perfectly fine. As you say it seems however you have gone about creating this table does not qualify it as a *named range*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Named ranges are maintained at the workbook level, not at the worksheet level; and your available methods to get details of a named range are:

```
$objPHPExcel->getNamedRanges();
```

to retrieve an array of named range objects, detailing all named ranges in the workbook

and

```
$objPHPExcel->getNamedRanges('Table1');
```

to retrieve a specified named range object by its name

Methods for the named range object include:

- getWorksheet()
- getRange()
- getLocalOnly()
- getScope()

Which provide information about the worksheet and cells to which that particular named range applies